# Clear the app's entire cache

Tags: ios, caching

The app has 8 screens. 
1 screen has a button that will clear any cache that has been set in the app in a single click.

How is that accomplished?

Comment: youcan remove the contents of NSCachesDirectory!

Comment: What is "the cache of the entire app"?

Comment: thanks @TejaNandamuri

Comment: @matt, it means to clear anything in the app that has been cached.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
NSString *strCacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *strPath = [strCacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourCacheDirectoryName"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL isFileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strPath];
if (isFileExists)
{
   BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];
   if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```